# How to save a array list permanently

Tags: android

I was wondering how can I save and arraylist "x" permanently. I am working on a music player that retrieves the songs on the sd card and saves them in the arraylist "x". Everytime I reopen the activity the list "x" is recreated eventhough it is already created, which in turn consumes the battery of the phone. How can I save the list permanently so that it is not recreated but is just loaded by the app???

Comment: Are you wanting the ArrayList to outlast the lifetime of the Activity? Or just survive through configuration changes (like rotation)? I guess I'm really asking what you mean by "re-open the activity"...

Comment: I would prefer to conserve it forever because I will be reusing it again and again. If I recreate the list it consumes cpu and in turn battery. Would it be a good idea to save permanently the list and just re-use it?

Comment: Depends on the size of the list, it might not be worth it. If its a 'small' list you wont notice the difference. Btw storing and retrieving the list also consumes cpu

Comment: so if it is a list of about a minimum of 100 songs? Please note that I do not use media store to query rather I use a method to reiterate through all folders in the sd card. The method I use is in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589417/how-to-query-the-media-store-to-find-songs-in-internal-and-external-memory

Comment: "a minimum of 100" more interested in the maximum :-P there is a big difference between 100 and 500,000

Answer (score 0):

You should save the ArrayList to the DB.